# Minimal filter of a power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Let $\mathbb{A} \subset P(A)$ non-empty and $\mathbb{A}$ have finite intersection property, Let $\mathbb{A} \subset F,F' $ such that $F,F'$ are filters and 
$F = \{ X : \exists T (T \subset \mathbb{A} , |T| < \aleph_0 , \bigcap T \subset X \subset A) \}$ and the question asks to prove that $F \subset F'$.

I assumes that $X \in F$ but $X \not\in F'$ from the fact that $X \in F$ , there is $T \subset \mathbb{A}$ such that $|T| < \aleph_0$ and $\bigcap T \subset X$

From here I want to arrive to contradiction, but I don't know how?

Note : $F$ is a filter means that :

1) $F$ is not empty and $A \in F$ and $F \subset P(A)$

2) $F$ have the finite intersection property meaning for all $B \subset F$ that is not empty we have that $\bigcap B \not= \emptyset$

3) If $B \in F$ and $B \subset C \subset A$ then $C \in F$

Comment: I think this should be the other way around, and you should prove $F \subset F'$. Correct me if i'm wrong tho.

Comment: Yes, i checked and indeed the filter $F$ constructed in this manner is minimal.

Comment: I think your definition of a filter needs one more clause: If $X$ and $Y$ are in $F$ then $X \cap Y$ is in $F$ too.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri true, i will edit

Comment: $F$ is called the  filter on $A$ that is generated by $\Bbb A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove $F \subset F'$. Suppose $X \in F$ so we have some finite $T = \{ Y_1, ..., Y_n\} \subset \mathbb{A}$ such that $\cap T = Y_1 \cap ... \cap Y_n \subset X$. Ok now lets look at $F'$. $\mathbb{A} \subset F'$ so we have $Y_i \in F'$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Now because $F'$ is a filter we can easily see that $Y_1 \cap ... \cap Y_n \in F'$ and again since $F'$ is a filter, it should be upward closed and must contain all subsets of $A$ that contain $Y_1 \cap ... \cap Y_n$, and since $X$ contains this too, we conclude that $X \in F'$.

Comment: very good, but how you derive that if $X,Y \in F'$ then $X \cap Y \in F'$, this is not part of  filters definition in the book.

Comment: I think that you might have misread the book, it might have said that $F$ is "closed" under finite intersection not that it has the finite intersection property.

Comment: thanks ,my bad lol, it does say that its closed under intersection.